# Uncaught ReferenceError with jQuery, Primefaces and Java

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I'm doing a small system with Java 1.8.0_162 and PrimeFaces 6.2.3.

I have a tabView with a "view" id and a widgetVar "tabView"

When I click on the search button I get some errors referencing jQuery and saying that "tabView is not defined"

[Here we can see the button that you press and the errors that it throws to the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRJ5I.png)

The code used for the button is:

```
<p:commandButton id="calcular" action="#{filtroAnalisisMacro.calculoOperaciones}"  title="Efectuar cálculo" icon="ui-icon-search" update="datos" oncomplete="tabView.select(0)"/>
```

And the objective of the button is to activate a tabView and to see the first tab.

```
<p:tabView style="width: 1200px" id="vista" widgetVar="tabView">
   <p:tab title="Gráfica" >
       ...
   </p:tab>
   <p:tab id="detalle" title="Detalle">
       ...
   </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

From here I can not continue, any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, couple of things. 1: Please read [ask] and importantly the [mcve] thing. It is very important. 2: Also if you put versions in the title, you indirectly state it fails with these but works with other versions. Try and correct the title. 3: Did you search for 'Uncaught ReferenceError' in google? [ask] sort of requests this and keep track and mention the posts you found that did not help. Cheers!

Comment: Done, and any suggestions about my doubt?

Comment: You did 2 but not 1 and 3 yet 2 is the least important one. I did not downvote yet but check  http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: Oncomplete is a client side call. In the client you must use `PF(widgetVar)` to get the requested object. `PF('tabView').select(0)` will do it.